# How to visualize the peaks in a signal with window size

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, signal-processing

I am trying to visualize some signal peaks with window size. but it doesn't give the right result I expect. This is my code below

```
'''
def extract_beat(signal, qrs_pos, win_msec=40, fs=360, start_beat=100, end_beat=300):
    signal = np.array(signal)
    print(signal.shape)
    #beat_array = np.zeros(start_beat+end_beat)#number of channels
    start = max(qrs_pos-start_beat,0)
    stop=start+start_beat+end_beat 
    #print(beat_array.shape,signal.shape)
    beat =  signal[qrs_pos-start:qrs_pos+stop]
    beat_array=np.pad(beat,start_beat+start_beat,mode='constant')
    label = np.zeros(len(beat))
    win = fs*win_msec//1000 
    label[start_beat-win:start_beat+win]=1
    return beat_array, label  '''
'''
'''
#test extract_beat
from scipy.misc import electrocardiogram

x = electrocardiogram()[:3500]
qrs_pos = [1,100,3500]
plt.plot(x)
for q in qrs_pos:
    y,label = extract_beat(x,q)
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(y)
    plt.plot(label)
```

This is the output I get

[image]

But I am expecting an output like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code
`beat_array=np.pad(beat,start_beat+start_beat,mode='constant')` you add 200 samples on each side of the array (2x`start_beat`).
When you later assign the label, you use the array size of `beat` and not `beat_array` so with a `start_beat` value of 100 you're off by 200.